# Не могу понять в чем ошибки в программе

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//глобальная константа:
const int n=3;
const int n1=2;
//Функция для отображения элементов двумерного массива:
void show(int M[n][n1]){
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n1;j++){
            //Оторажение элементов массива:
            printf("%4d",M[i][j]);
        }
        //Переход к новой строке:
        printf("\n");
   }
}
int fam;
int fam1;
int fam2;

//Главная функция программы:
int main(){
//Изменение кодировки консоли:
system("chcp 1251>nul");
cout<<"Ваше фамилия    -   " ;
cin>>fam;
cout<<"Ваше фамилия    -   " ;
cin>>fam1;
cout<<"Ваше фамилия    -   " ;
cin>>fam2;

//Объявление и инициализация двухмерного массива:
int A[n][n1]={{fam,231},{fam1,231},{fam2,231}};
printf("Матрица А:\n");
//Оторажение содержимого массива:
show(A);
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Что это у вас вместо фамилии номер?

Comment: а что вы хотели сделать?

Comment: cout<<"Ваше фамилия    -   " ;   тут вы наверняка  вводите строку, которой программа заставляет преобразовываться в целое число, что приведет к неопределенному  поведению или выдаст 0 ( не пробовал такое делать )

Comment: Согласен с  AR Hovsepyan.И как исправить?

Comment: создать свой класс и использовать контейнеры стд